# Can we debug aspx Web Application with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code

As the title, I have question in mind, can we debug a web application (aspx) under Visual studio code?
so far, I'm using Visual studio 2015 Community to implement and deploy the web application.

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score -2):

You want to debug the aspx.cs or aspx.vb file? You can simply run the application from visual studio or attach the w3wp process from Debug -> Attach to Process menu option.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w9dfyd8.aspx

Comment: Thank you, @devC
I'm able to debug aspx.cs or aspx.vb under Visual Studio but with Visual Studio Code , I couldn't. That is what I try to looking for.